# Вывод определенного списка файлов, сортировка

Tags: linux, файлы, bash, сортировка, консоль

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу.
Есть директория `lab0`, в которой находятся файлы и ещё директории.

> Задание:
>
> Рекурсивно вывести содержимое файлов с номерами строк из директории `lab0`, имя которых начинается на `d`, строки отсортировать по имени `a -> z`, ошибки доступа перенаправить в файл в директории `/tmp`

Пробовал сделать так:

```
grep -hn '^d' ~/lab0/ | sort -t: -k2d 2>/tmp/err
```

Но после выполнения команды терминал просто молчит:

[image: terminal]

Comment: "Просто молчит" — это потому что ругань грепа на неверный аргумент вы отправили в `/tmp/err`. А так он не молчит, а очень информативно сообщает, где ошибка.

Comment: Если убрать перенаправление, то результат тот же

Comment: Вам же надо выбирать **имена файлов, начинающиеся на 'd'**, так что `grep` тут не годится. Читайте [man find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: Вы путаете первую букву **имени** файла с его **содержимым**. Смотрите, должно быть что-то типа `sort $(find lab0 -mindepth=1 -maxdepth=1 -type f -name '^d*' 2>/tmp/err)`.